# How to do active learning in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, active-learning

I am currently working on a problem where I don't have a plethora of labeled data. I therefore want to use active learning to try and label some of my data using the model and then have all images (in this case) with a low confidence threshold be sent off for annotation. Are there any built in or peripheral techniques/packages in the FluxML ecosystem that would enable this? I looked around but did not see active learning techniques mentioned at all for Flux. In PyTorch for example, one of the resources I use is this [PyTorch for Active learning repo](https://github.com/rmunro/pytorch_active_learning).